# How to display file in console page by page in VxWorks?

Tags: vxworks

In VxWorks console, command "copy " can display its content to console. But if the file is too big, I prefer to display it page by page. In Linux or Windows, I can use " | more" appended to a command to have a shown contents displayed page by page. In VxWorks, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

In a similar way - use more.

This relies on using the vxworks cmd shell, rather than the C interpreter (which is usually the default).

eg:

```
->cmd
[vxworks *]#ls
bigFile.txt
[vxworks *]#more bigFile.txt
```

will display:

```
Long
Block
Of
Text
--- 'q' to quit, any key to continue ----
Yet
More
Text
--- 'q' to quit, any key to continue ----
```

Comment: My VxWorks version is 5.0.5. I got "undefined sysmobl: more" when I used 'more' as told. That's, it doesn't work.

Comment: The "more" command requires the command shell, rather than the C  interpreter shell. I don't think this was available in VxWorks 5

Comment: I tested it in command shell. You're right that it's not available at VxWorks 5.0.4. I wonder which version of VxWorks you verified 'more' command.

Comment: By the way, a similar question: What is the similar command in VxWorks as in Linux: "ls > tmp.txt". That is, how to redirect display output at console to a file.

Comment: You should ask that as a new question... But I think the same syntax

Comment: The details may vary depending on which interpreter , and version